# How to left align the y-axis labels D3 Chart

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js

How to left align the y-axis labels in d3?
tried using the .orient(left) but it doesn't help.
Tried transforming the labels.
Please help on this aligning the labels to the left
Example:
Good
Very Good
Very
Good1
Very Good1
Very1
Good
Very Good
Very
Good1
Very Good1
Very1
Good
Very Good
Very
Good1
Very Good1
Very1
Good
Very Good
Very
Good1
Very Good1
Very1

```js
const data = [{name: 'Good', value: 1}, {name: 'Very Good', value: 2}, {name: 'Very', value: 1}, {name: 'Good1', value: 1}, {name: 'Very Good1', value: 2}, {name: 'Very1', value: 1}, {name: 'Good2', value: 1}, {name: 'Very Good2', value: 2}, {name: 'Very2', value: 1},{name: 'Good3', value: 1}, {name: 'Very Good3', value: 2}, {name: 'Very3', value: 1},{name: 'Good4', value: 1}, {name: 'Very Good5', value: 2}, {name: 'Very5', value: 1},{name: 'Good6', value: 1}, {name: 'Very Good6', value: 2}, {name: 'Very6', value: 1},{name: 'Good7', value: 1}, {name: 'Very Good7', value: 2}, {name: 'Very7', value: 1},{name: 'Good8', value: 1}, {name: 'Very Good8', value: 2}, {name: 'Very9', value: 1}];
// We want to center each rect around the value it's supposed to have.
// That means that we need to have a node width
let nodeWidth = 33;
let nodeHeight = 18;
if (this.viewBy !== 'Overlapping ' + this.jobOrSkill) {
  nodeWidth = 60;
  nodeHeight = 18;
}
let height = 1000;
const width = 620,
  paddingLeft = 0,
  paddingTop = 0,
  margin = {
    top: 20,
    left: 140,
    right: 40,
    bottom: 40
};
if (this.totalSkills && this.totalSkills.length < 10) {
  height = 250;
}
if (this.totalSkills && this.totalSkills.length > 10 && this.totalSkills.length < 20) {
  height = 400;
}
if (this.totalSkills && this.totalSkills.length > 20 && this.totalSkills.length < 30) {
  height = 600;
}
const innerWidth = width + (margin.left + margin.right);
const innerHeight = height + (margin.top + margin.bottom);
// We also need to make sure there is space for all nodes, even at the edges.
// One way to get this is by just extending the domain a little.
const domain = d3.extent(data.map(d => Math.round(d.value)));
const x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([Math.round(domain[0]) - 1, Math.round(domain[1]) + 1])
  .range([0, width]);

const y = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(data.map((d, i) => d.name && d.name.length > 20 ? d.name = d.name.slice(0, 20) + '...' : d.name = d.name))
  .range([height, 0])
  .padding(1);

const svg = d3.select('#comparisionChartData')
  .attr('width', width + margin.left)
  .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

const g = svg
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left} ${margin.right})`);

g.append('g')
  .classed('x-axis', true)
  .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height})`)
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

d3.selectAll('.y-axis').selectAll('.tick')
  .append('svg:title')
  .data(data)
  .text(function (d) {
    return d.name;
  });

g.append('g')
  .classed('y-axis', true)
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y).tickPadding(10));
const bars = g.append('g')
  .selectAll('rect')
  .data(data)
  .attr('stroke', '#e5e5e5')
  .attr('class', 'line');

bars.exit().remove();

// All the same until here
bars.enter()
  .append('rect')
  // width has become a constant
  .attr('width', nodeWidth)
  // Now, transform each node so it centers around the value it's supposed to have
  .attr('transform', `translate(${-nodeWidth / 2} -8)`)
  // .merge(bars)
  // `x` denotes the placement directly again
  .attr('x', d => x(Math.round(d.value)))
  .attr('y', d => y(d.name))
  .attr('height', nodeHeight)
  .attr('fill', d => Math.round(d.value) > 0 && this.viewBy === 'Overlapping ' + this.jobOrSkill ? '#648fff' :
    this.viewBy === 'Overlapping ' + this.jobOrSkill && Math.round(d.value) === 0 ? '#9a16ca' :
    this.viewBy === 'Overlapping ' + this.jobOrSkill && Math.round(d.value) < 0 ? '#dc267f' :
    this.viewBy === 'Unique to Organization' ? '#016970' : this.viewBy === 'Absent to Organization' ? '#757575' : '#648fff');

// Now one more thing, we want to add labels to each node.
// `<rect>` can't have children, we we add them to the plot seperately
// using the same `data` as for the bars
const labels = g.append('g')
  .selectAll('text')
  .data(data);

labels.exit().remove();

labels.enter()
  .append('text')
  .attr('fill', 'white')
  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle') // center-align the text
  // .merge(bars)
  // `x` denotes the placement directly
  .attr('x', d => x(Math.round(d.value)))
  // Add half a bar's height to target the center of each node
  .attr('y', d => y(d.name) + y.bandwidth() / 4)
  // Actually fill in the text this.viewBy === 'Overlapping ' + this.jobOrSkill ? '+' + Math.round(d.value) :
  .text(d => Math.round(d.value) > 0 && this.viewBy === 'Overlapping ' + this.jobOrSkill ? Math.round(d.value)
  : this.viewBy === 'Unique to Organization' ? 'Unique' : this.viewBy === 'Absent to Organization' ? 'Absent' : Math.round(d.value))
  .attr('title', d => y(d.name))
  .attr('transform', `translate(0, 0)`)
  .attr('dy', 5);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg id="comparisionChartData"></svg>
```

Comment: Your code is not working, but do you mean `.attr('text-anchor', 'start')`?

Comment: Thanks Ruben for answer but if we use this it will overlap on grids .attr('text-anchor', 'start')

Comment: In that case, please make your snippet work so we can better see what you want

Comment: Ruben,Working example in code pen but the labels or overlapped. https://codepen.io/nchetankumar/pen/PozGmdy

Comment: I get the error `"SyntaxError: missing ) in parenthetical",` when I try to run it

Comment: code pen included above

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get it with a combination of `text-anchor: start` and `transform(-60, 0)`:

```js
const data = [{
  name: 'Good',
  value: 1
}, {
  name: 'Very Good',
  value: 2
}, {
  name: 'Very',
  value: 1
}, {
  name: 'Good1',
  value: 1
}, {
  name: 'Very Good1',
  value: 2
}, {
  name: 'Very1',
  value: 1
}, {
  name: 'Good2',
  value: 1
}, {
  name: 'Very Good2',
  value: 2
}, {
  name: 'Very2',
  value: 1
}, {
  name: 'Good3',
  value: 1
}, {
  name: 'Very Good3',
  value: 2
}, {
  name: 'Very3',
  value: 1
}, {
  name: 'Good4',
  value: 1
}, {
  name: 'Very Good5',
  value: 2
}, {
  name: 'Very5',
  value: 1
}, {
  name: 'Good6',
  value: 1
}, {
  name: 'Very Good6',
  value: 2
}, {
  name: 'Very6',
  value: 1
}, {
  name: 'Good7',
  value: 1
}, {
  name: 'Very Good7',
  value: 2
}, {
  name: 'Very7',
  value: 1
}, {
  name: 'Good8',
  value: 1
}, {
  name: 'Very Good8',
  value: 2
}, {
  name: 'Very9',
  value: 1
}];
// We want to center each rect around the value it's supposed to have.
// That means that we need to have a node width
let nodeWidth = 33;
let nodeHeight = 18;
if (this.viewBy !== 'Overlapping ' + this.jobOrSkill) {
  nodeWidth = 60;
  nodeHeight = 18;
}
let height = 1000;
const width = 620,
  paddingLeft = 0,
  paddingTop = 0,
  margin = {
    top: 20,
    left: 140,
    right: 40,
    bottom: 40
  };
if (this.totalSkills && this.totalSkills.length < 10) {
  height = 250;
}
if (this.totalSkills && this.totalSkills.length > 10 && this.totalSkills.length < 20) {
  height = 400;
}
if (this.totalSkills && this.totalSkills.length > 20 && this.totalSkills.length < 30) {
  height = 600;
}
const innerWidth = width + (margin.left + margin.right);
const innerHeight = height + (margin.top + margin.bottom);
// We also need to make sure there is space for all nodes, even at the edges.
// One way to get this is by just extending the domain a little.
const domain = d3.extent(data.map(d => Math.round(d.value)));
const x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([Math.round(domain[0]) - 1, Math.round(domain[1]) + 1])
  .range([0, width]);

const y = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(data.map((d, i) => d.name && d.name.length > 20 ? d.name = d.name.slice(0, 20) + '...' : d.name = d.name))
  .range([height, 0])
  .padding(1);

const svg = d3.select('#comparisionChartData')
  .attr('width', width + margin.left)
  .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

const g = svg
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left} ${margin.right})`);

g.append('g')
  .classed('x-axis', true)
  .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height})`)
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

g.append('g')
  .classed('y-axis', true)
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y).tickPadding(10))
  .selectAll("text")
  .attr("transform", "translate(-60, 0)")
  .attr("text-anchor", "start")
  .append("title")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d;
  });

const bars = g.append('g')
  .selectAll('rect')
  .data(data)
  .attr('stroke', '#e5e5e5')
  .attr('class', 'line');

bars.exit().remove();

// All the same until here
bars.enter()
  .append('rect')
  // width has become a constant
  .attr('width', nodeWidth)
  // Now, transform each node so it centers around the value it's supposed to have
  .attr('transform', `translate(${-nodeWidth / 2} -8)`)
  // .merge(bars)
  // `x` denotes the placement directly again
  .attr('x', d => x(Math.round(d.value)))
  .attr('y', d => y(d.name))
  .attr('height', nodeHeight)
  .attr('fill', d => Math.round(d.value) > 0 && this.viewBy === 'Overlapping ' + this.jobOrSkill ? '#648fff' :
    this.viewBy === 'Overlapping ' + this.jobOrSkill && Math.round(d.value) === 0 ? '#9a16ca' :
    this.viewBy === 'Overlapping ' + this.jobOrSkill && Math.round(d.value) < 0 ? '#dc267f' :
    this.viewBy === 'Unique to Organization' ? '#016970' : this.viewBy === 'Absent to Organization' ? '#757575' : '#648fff');

// Now one more thing, we want to add labels to each node.
// `<rect>` can't have children, we we add them to the plot seperately
// using the same `data` as for the bars
const labels = g.append('g')
  .selectAll('text')
  .data(data);

labels.exit().remove();

labels.enter()
  .append('text')
  .attr('fill', 'white')
  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle') // center-align the text
  // .merge(bars)
  // `x` denotes the placement directly
  .attr('x', d => x(Math.round(d.value)))
  // Add half a bar's height to target the center of each node
  .attr('y', d => y(d.name) + y.bandwidth() / 4)
  // Actually fill in the text this.viewBy === 'Overlapping ' + this.jobOrSkill ? '+' + Math.round(d.value) :
  .text(d => Math.round(d.value) > 0 && this.viewBy === 'Overlapping ' + this.jobOrSkill ? Math.round(d.value) :
    this.viewBy === 'Unique to Organization' ? 'Unique' : this.viewBy === 'Absent to Organization' ? 'Absent' : Math.round(d.value))
  .attr('title', d => y(d.name))
  .attr('transform', `translate(0, 0)`)
  .attr('dy', 5);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg id="comparisionChartData"></svg>
```

Comment: That was helped a lot thanks Ruben. Is there any way we can also show the title on hover of the y-axis labels?

Comment: You mean the label itself? I added that to the answer. `.append("title").text(function(d) { return d; });`

Comment: Fix the position of a x-axis and scroll only y-axis and add % symbol to the x-axis values with out decimal points. Can you do me a favor for this Ruben?
For Y-axis is there a way to add dotted lines?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, sorry. It also sounds like you're asking multiple questions at once

Comment: Hoo sorry for confusion.
1) Fix the position of the x-axis it shouldn't scroll
2) In x-axis values are like -2.5, -2.0, -1.5, -1.0, 0, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5
Expected is: -2.5%, 2.0%, -1.5%, -1.0%, 0%, 1.0%, 1.5%, 2.0%, 2.5%
3) How to add dotted lines to the y-axis?

Comment: Please ask a new question. Be detailed and specific. You're asking for a lot, and comments are not meant for these kinds of follow-up. Also, this way you'll attract the entire SO audience for an answer instead of just me

Comment: Please find the new question link,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64483946/fix-the-x-axis-of-d3-js-and-add-dotted-lines-to-the-y-axis-and-x-axis