# Fix the x-axis of D3 JS and add dotted lines to the y-axis and x-axis

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, d3.js, bar-chart

Any help on how to do below implementations in D3 JS?

1. Fix the position of the x-axis it shouldn't scroll
2. In x-axis values are like -2.5, -2.0, -1.5, -1.0, 0, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5 Expected is: -2.5%, 2.0%, -1.5%, -1.0%, 0%, 1.0%, 1.5%, 2.0%, 2.5%
3. How to add dotted lines to the y-axis?

Code pen:
https://codepen.io/nchetankumar/pen/PozGmdy

```
const data = [{
  name: 'Good',
  value: 1
}, {
  name: 'Very Good',
  value: 2
}, {
  name: 'Very',
  value: 1
}, {
  name: 'Good1',
  value: 1
}, {
  name: 'Very Good1',
  value: 2
}, {
  name: 'Very1',
  value: 1
}, {
  name: 'Good2',
  value: 1
}, {
  name: 'Very Good2',
  value: 2
}, {
  name: 'Very2',
  value: 1
}, {
  name: 'Good3',
  value: 1
}, {
  name: 'Very Good3',
  value: 2
}, {
  name: 'Very3',
  value: 1
}, {
  name: 'Good4',
  value: 1
}, {
  name: 'Very Good5',
  value: 2
}, {
  name: 'Very5',
  value: 1
}, {
  name: 'Good6',
  value: 1
}, {
  name: 'Very Good6',
  value: 2
}, {
  name: 'Very6',
  value: 1
}, {
  name: 'Good7',
  value: 1
}, {
  name: 'Very Good7',
  value: 2
}, {
  name: 'Very7',
  value: 1
}, {
  name: 'Good8',
  value: 1
}, {
  name: 'Very Good8',
  value: 2
}, {
  name: 'Very9',
  value: 1
}];
// We want to center each rect around the value it's supposed to have.
// That means that we need to have a node width
let nodeWidth = 33;
let nodeHeight = 18;
if (this.viewBy !== 'Overlapping ' + this.jobOrSkill) {
  nodeWidth = 60;
  nodeHeight = 18;
}
let height = 1000;
const width = 620,
  paddingLeft = 0,
  paddingTop = 0,
  margin = {
    top: 20,
    left: 140,
    right: 40,
    bottom: 40
  };
if (this.totalSkills && this.totalSkills.length < 10) {
  height = 250;
}
if (this.totalSkills && this.totalSkills.length > 10 && this.totalSkills.length < 20) {
  height = 400;
}
if (this.totalSkills && this.totalSkills.length > 20 && this.totalSkills.length < 30) {
  height = 600;
}
const innerWidth = width + (margin.left + margin.right);
const innerHeight = height + (margin.top + margin.bottom);
// We also need to make sure there is space for all nodes, even at the edges.
// One way to get this is by just extending the domain a little.
const domain = d3.extent(data.map(d => Math.round(d.value)));
const x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([Math.round(domain[0]) - 1, Math.round(domain[1]) + 1])
  .range([0, width]);

const y = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(data.map((d, i) => d.name && d.name.length > 20 ? d.name = d.name.slice(0, 20) + '...' : d.name = d.name))
  .range([height, 0])
  .padding(1);

const svg = d3.select('#comparisionChartData')
  .attr('width', width + margin.left)
  .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

const g = svg
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left} ${margin.right})`);

g.append('g')
  .classed('x-axis', true)
  .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height})`)
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

g.append('g')
  .classed('y-axis', true)
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y).tickPadding(10))
  .selectAll("text")
  .attr("transform", "translate(-60, 0)")
  .attr("text-anchor", "start")
  .append("title")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d;
  });

const bars = g.append('g')
  .selectAll('rect')
  .data(data)
  .attr('stroke', '#e5e5e5')
  .attr('class', 'line');

bars.exit().remove();

// All the same until here
bars.enter()
  .append('rect')
  // width has become a constant
  .attr('width', nodeWidth)
  // Now, transform each node so it centers around the value it's supposed to have
  .attr('transform', `translate(${-nodeWidth / 2} -8)`)
  // .merge(bars)
  // `x` denotes the placement directly again
  .attr('x', d => x(Math.round(d.value)))
  .attr('y', d => y(d.name))
  .attr('height', nodeHeight)
  .attr('fill', d => Math.round(d.value) > 0 && this.viewBy === 'Overlapping ' + this.jobOrSkill ? '#648fff' :
    this.viewBy === 'Overlapping ' + this.jobOrSkill && Math.round(d.value) === 0 ? '#9a16ca' :
    this.viewBy === 'Overlapping ' + this.jobOrSkill && Math.round(d.value) < 0 ? '#dc267f' :
    this.viewBy === 'Unique to Organization' ? '#016970' : this.viewBy === 'Absent to Organization' ? '#757575' : '#648fff');

// Now one more thing, we want to add labels to each node.
// `<rect>` can't have children, we we add them to the plot seperately
// using the same `data` as for the bars
const labels = g.append('g')
  .selectAll('text')
  .data(data);

labels.exit().remove();

labels.enter()
  .append('text')
  .attr('fill', 'white')
  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle') // center-align the text
  // .merge(bars)
  // `x` denotes the placement directly
  .attr('x', d => x(Math.round(d.value)))
  // Add half a bar's height to target the center of each node
  .attr('y', d => y(d.name) + y.bandwidth() / 4)
  // Actually fill in the text this.viewBy === 'Overlapping ' + this.jobOrSkill ? '+' + Math.round(d.value) :
  .text(d => Math.round(d.value) > 0 && this.viewBy === 'Overlapping ' + this.jobOrSkill ? Math.round(d.value) :
    this.viewBy === 'Unique to Organization' ? 'Unique' : this.viewBy === 'Absent to Organization' ? 'Absent' : Math.round(d.value))
  .attr('title', d => y(d.name))
  .attr('transform', `translate(0, 0)`)
  .attr('dy', 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

1 - I dont quite understand the first question, because the xAxis seem
to be fixed and not scrolling.

2 - The x-axis values seem to be all positive. But nevertheless you can get the desired format with the vales if you call the x-axis ticks like that:

```js
.call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickFormat(function(d) { return d+"%" }));
```

This will also show the minus if the value is negative.

I'd personally recommend to map the vales to fractions of 1 (2.5% would be 0.025 ) and just:

```js
.call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickFormat(d3.format(".0%"));
```

3 - For gridlines you can see sample code here: https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/879316f32be861b6870c98a277076d1b with `.attr('stroke-dasharray'='2');`

Comment: Thanks for help.
Regarding 1st point,
The height is auto but if we restrict the height to 500px and the content is scrollable in that case the x-axis also scrolling. 
If the chart is scrollable in that case x-axis shouldn't scroll.

Comment: So the x-axis should stay in place. What you are looking for is an pannable chart, where one axis is scrollable.
There is a example of this here: https://observablehq.com/@nicholasblexrud/pannable-chart-w-dual-y-axis where ```const body = parent.append("div").style("overflow-x", "scroll").style("-webkit-overflow-scrolling", "touch");```and ```body.node().scrollBy(overwidth, 0)```;`do the magic. 
You only need to adapt this for the y-Axis, instead of x.